# Monotonic functions: sup and inf

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

let $f$ be monotonically increasing on (a,b), if c ∈ (a,b) prove that:

limSup(x) = $f(c^+)$

limInf(x) = $f(c^-)$

I'm not sure where to start, especially that i'm not very profound in fully grasping the Sup and Inf concepts, I sort of always make mistakes. can someone please help me where to start?

Help is greatly appreciated! thank you

Comment: How are $c^+$ and $c^-$ defined?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already covered this, you should start off by showing that  $$ f(c^{-}) \leq f(c) \leq f(c^{+})$$ 
where $f(c^{-}) = \sup\{f(x) : x \in (a, \: c)\}$ and $f(c^{+}) = \inf\{f(x) : x \in (c, \: b)\}$.

Since $f$ is monotone increasing, what can you say about
$$\limsup_{x \to c} f(c) = \inf_{\delta > 0} \: (\sup\{f(x) : x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta), x \neq c\})$$